# Find the factorization of the polynomial as a product of irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, factoring

Find the factorization of the polynomial $x^5-x^4+8x^3-8x^2+16x-16$ as a product of irreducible on rings $R[x]$ and $C[x]$

Testing with the simplest possible root in this case, $P(1)=0$

Applying the schema of Ruffini

$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
  & 1 & -1 & 8 & -8 & 16 & -16 \\
1 &  & 1 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 16 \\
\hline  
  & 1 & 0 & 8  &0 &16 & 0 \\
\end{array}
$

$P(x)=(x-1).(x^4+8x^2+16)$

$P(x)=(x-1).(x^2+4)^2 \rightarrow Irreducible$ $in$ $R[x]$

So, I must to factorize this to make it irreducible in $C[x]$

Applying Bhaskara in $(x^2+4)^2$ $a=1; b=0; c=4$

$$\frac{\pm\sqrt{-4.1.4}}{2}=\frac{\pm\sqrt{-16}}{2}= R_1, R_2$$
$R_1=-2i$

$R_2=2i$

So (...)

$P(x)= (x-2i).(x+2i).(x-1) \rightarrow Irreducible $ $in $ $C[x]$

this is well done?

Comment: Almost. You need $(x-2i)^2(x+2i)^2(x-1)$. Remember there was an $(x^2+4)^2$.